# Can I add multiple keyframe animation to same property for same object

Tags: animation

I am using the 3D model from ReadyPlayerMe and it has a blend shape called "mouth_smile".

I change the range to -1 to 1 to establish sad and smiley face
but the problem is that when I done the smiley face, I need to add new keyframe which will overlap the smiley face.

And I have seen people said that action editor can create new action but after some try it seem that it only support keyframe for loc/rot/scale. So the keyframe for blend shape will still overlap even if I use the action editor.

[image: Screenshot#1]

(Should there be a diamond in the timeline?)

[image: Screenshot#2]

I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Shape Key actions are in the Shape Key Editor. You can stack actions in the NLA editor, but the result will not be different than without it. Much like in photosop you can paint on a new layer but you can do the same on the original layer. What is your goal here? If you have one action at -1 and the other at 1, depending the blend mode you chose it wills just set the shapekey to either -1, 0 or 1.